# setInterval function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning setInterval in JavaScript for the first time, and am trying to show a value after 5 seconds. My code is given below:

```
<button onclick="myTest()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myTest() {
    const ret = myFunction();
    alert(ret);
}

function myFunction() {
    let i = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        i += 1;
        if (i === 5) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return i;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

I want 5 to be alerted, instead I am getting `undefined`. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `myFunction` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: You can't return anything from the anonymous function within the `setInterval` call. You need to write to the `console` from within that function

Comment: Actually there is no need to declare `ret` and `interval` as `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return anything from the anonymous function within the `setInterval` call. You need to write to the `console` from within that function. Try this:

```js
function myTest() {
  // this function is now redundant - you could call myFunction() directly
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  let i = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
    i += 1;
    if (i === 5) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log(i); // this will appear after 5 seconds...
    }
  }, 1000);
}

myTest();
```

Comment: Ok, yes, that worked! I didn't know about not being about to return from the setInterval function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's a general rule with asynchronous code, you can't return a value synchronously

Answer (score 1):

```
return i;
```

i will be returned to Window (I guess), not to myFunction.

myFunction return undefined by default as you did not write a return .

```
function myTest() {
    myFunction(function(val){
        alert(val);
    });
}

function myFunction(callback) {
    let i = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        i += 1;
        if (i === 5) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            if(callback){
                callback(i);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

you can get your value in a callback function .

Answer (score 1):

The alert(ret) will occur before 5 seconds are     over and thus my function will return undefined.     Try this way.

```
<button onclick="myTest()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myTest() {
myFunction();
}
function myFunction() {
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){  
   i++;
    if (i === 5) {
    alert(i);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);

}
 </script>
```